# Set Default System Options

Tags: parallelization, mac-os-x, benchmarking

I have a new Mac M1 machine and am getting Mathematica set up on it. I noticed that when I run some simple benchmarking tests, for example matrix diagonalization, the code runs significantly slower if I use the default ParallelOptions as compared to if I set the ParallelOptions to run on only 4 cores. For example:

```
n = 1000;
A = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
B = A + ConjugateTranspose[A];
Eigenvalues[B] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.27 seconds*)

SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 4];
n = 1000;
A = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
B = A + ConjugateTranspose[A];
Eigenvalues[B] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.08 seconds*)
```

I would like to find a way to always have Mathematica boot up with the ParallelThreadNumber set to 4 rather than the default, which is 8. It doesn't seem like this setting saves upon closing and reopening the program. How should I get it to remember this as the new default setting in order to not have to set it each time?

Comment: See [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html).